# $ \left\lfloor\frac{x - \pi(z)^*}{n} \right\rfloor\geq\left\lfloor\frac{x-z^*}{m}\right\rfloor $ whenever $n\mid m$ and $\pi:\Bbb{Z}/m\to\Bbb{Z}/n$✨

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, ceiling-and-floor-functions, ring-homomorphism

If $z \in \Bbb{Z}/n$, w let $z^* =$ the standard residue or in other words the least non-negative integer equal to $z$ modulo $n$. Suppose that $n \mid m$ for some two *positive* integers $n,m$.

If $\pi : \Bbb{Z}/m \twoheadrightarrow \Bbb{Z}/n$ is the ring surjection, it's always true that:

$$
\left\lfloor\frac{x - \pi(z)^*}{n} \right\rfloor \geq \left\lfloor\frac{x - z^*}{m}\right\rfloor
$$

for all $x \in \Bbb{Z}$ and $z \in \Bbb{Z}/m$.  In particular, if we must use this, my application is such that $z$ solves $z^2 = 1\mod m$.

If $n \lt m$ in addition, can we say that the conjectured inequality is strict as well?

Also, in my application $n,m$ are always square-free.  Use that if it needs it.

---

**Edit.** Please also assume that $x \geq 0$.  Because I just now found a proof, and I'll post as an answer, and $x\geq 0$ is suitable to my app as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's true for $x = 0$ because both floors evaluate to $-1$, as $r^* \lt m$ and $\pi(r)^* \lt n$ (as they are the standard residues).

Now assume that it's true for all $x = 0...X$.  Then at $x = X + 1$ we have:

$$
\lfloor \frac{ X + 1 - r^*}{m}\rfloor  = \lfloor\frac{ X - r^*}{m}\rfloor + (m \mid X + 1 -r^*)
$$

where $(m \mid z)$ simply takes on the value $1$ if $m$ divides $z$ and $0$ otherwise.

Similarly goes for the other side of the original inequality.  We have by inductive assumption that:

$$
\lfloor \frac{X - r^*}{m}\rfloor \leq \lfloor\frac{X-\pi(r)^*}{n} \rfloor
$$

Now simply add to that:

$$
(m \mid X + 1 - r^*) \leq (n\mid X + 1 - \pi(r)^*)
$$

which we will now prove.    If the LHS is $1$ then:

$$
X + 1 - r^* = 0 \pmod m \\
\implies X + 1 - \pi(r)^* = X + 1 - r^* = 0 \pmod n
$$

And so the RHS is also one.  This completes the proof.

$\blacksquare$